Antrl4 PLSQL differentiating between a variable and a function assignment
I am using Antlr4 with python to process PLSQL files.
The grammar is from here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql
I have been using this for a variety of purposes and it works very well for me.
I have a question though about the following type of expression:
   v_value1 := v_another_variable;
   v_value2 := get_value_from_this_function();

In both cases the parser/listener will evaluate both v_another_variable and get_value_from_this_function as Regular_idContext.
In my code I have a list of functions which I do a lookup on and if it matches I treat the item as a function.
I cannot think of another way to do this, but is there a better way?
Failing that is it possible to prime the Antlr listener with a list of functions so that it recognises these and emits an appropriate signal that can be handled e.g something like
def enterRegular_id_IsFunction(elf, ctx:PlSqlParser.Regular_id_IsFunctionContext):

The two symbols are differentiated by context. For function calls, the node general_element_part will contain at least one function_argment node. This is very easy to check by looking up the parent links until you find the general_element_partnode, then check the children of that node forfunction_argment`.

@kaby76 Thank you (again). I will try that. What does come to mind though is what about functions with no arguments? They may be rare, but do they exist in PLSQL, and you can even call these without the brackets, which is why I thought to have the known function names lookup.

Unfortunately, we can't distinguish function calls vs a variable ref. There's no symbol table. Before adding that though, the grammar needs a little cleaning. It's very slow.
